# UIImageView loading image very slowly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, nsurlsession

I have some code that gets an image from a web page and displays it in an ImageView. But the image loads very slowly for some reason I don't really understand! Through my logging I can see that all the data for the image (base64 string) arrives pretty instantly, yet it takes about 12 - 15 seconds for the image to appear in the ImageView.

I find this very strange because I used an NSStream to get the data for the image in a different method and the image loaded as soon as all the data arrived. But with this URLSession method its taking longer for the image to load. This doesn't really make sense! This method shouldn't affect how the ImageView loads that data.

Has anybody any ideas why this might be happening?

heres the code:

```
- (void)postMethod:(NSDictionary *)numDict
{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://theWebAddress.com/aPage.php"]; // add url to page
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";


NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:numDict options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSLog(@"%@", numDict);

if (!error)
{
    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:data completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        NSDictionary *diction = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];


        for (id key in diction)
        {
            if ([key isEqualToString:@"text"])
            {
                NSLog(@"data is text");

                self.messageLabel.text = diction[@"text"];

                break;
            }
            else if ([key isEqualToString:@"image"])
            {
                NSLog(@"data is an image");

                // gets the base64 string pretty instantly but takes 12 - 15 seconds to pop up in the imageView

                NSData *ImgData = [[NSData alloc] init];
                ImgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:diction[@"image"] options:1];

                self.ImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:ImgData];

                break;
            }
        }

    }];

    [uploadTask resume];
}
}
```

many thanks!

Comment: Why are you using an upload task?

Comment: because i'm posting some data to the web page, then the page outputs either text or an image based on that data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your completion handler might be operating on a background thread. UI updates should always work on the main thread. Put a break point at

```
self.ImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:ImgData];
```

and see if it is on the main thread. If not, dispatch it to the main thread before you set the ImageView.image:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.ImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:ImgData];
});
```

Comment: worked like a charm! although your code is missing a ^ from in front of the first {    ' dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ code }); ' Thanks very much!

Comment: yep, thanks for the note. wrote a quick answer in SO instead of xcode so i didn't catch it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use SDWebImage https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage and all you need is to set the image in imageView like this:

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are firstly downloading image and then showing image.You can download image by using lazy loading.

For this you can use EgoImageView not uiimageview.

self.ImageView.imageURL=[NSURL URLWithString:

here self.ImageView is of egoimageview type.

you can get this class from github.

https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading